# DOM traversal without exluded elements

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, dom, traversal

I'm creating a simple script that traverses the DOM and returns a tree object with the elements found in the DOM. Recursive traversal itself is quite simple but I want/need to skip certain elements and include other elements. How do I do this?

This is my HTML:

```html
<div data-element="from-here">
  <div>skip me</div>
  <div>
    <div data-element="awesome">awesome text</div>
    <div data-element="collect-me">
      awesome text
      <div data-element="also-me">
        other text
        <div class="but-not-me">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my recursive traversal code:

```js
const root = document.querySelector('[data-element="from-here"]');

function traverse(node) {
  return {
    element: node.dataset.element,
    children: Array.from(node.querySelectorAll(':scope > div')).map(childNode => traverse(childNode)),
  };
}

traverse(root);
```

As you can see the code queries all div elements but I only need the elements with a `data-element` attribute. I can't just do `node.querySelectorAll(':scope > [data-element]') because that won't reach past the first div.

This is the result I want:

```
{
  element: 'from-here',
  children: [
    {
      element: 'awesome',
      children: [],
    },
    {
      element: 'collect-me',
      children: [
        {
          element: 'also-me',
          children: [],
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a descendant selector instead of child combinator.

Comment: @Teemu that would return all decending elements on each iteration. I need the direct decendants but skip each elements that don't have the data-element attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `Array.prototype.flatMap` can drastically reduce the complexity of your transformation -

1. If the node does not have a `data-element` value,
2. Do not include the node; include only the results of its children.
3. Otherwise (by induction) the node *does* have a `data-element` value. Include this `element` in the output as well as this node's `children`.

Numbered points above correspond to source comments below -

```js
const root = document.querySelector('[data-element="from-here"]');

const toTree = ({ dataset = {}, children = [] }) =>
  dataset.element === undefined              // 1
    ? Array.from(children).flatMap(toTree)   // 2
    : [ { element: dataset.element           // 3
        , children: Array.from(children).flatMap(toTree)
        }
      ]

console.log(toTree(root)[0])
```

```html
<div data-element="from-here">
  <div>skip me</div>
  <div>
    <div data-element="awesome">awesome text</div>
    <div data-element="collect-me">
      awesome text
      <div data-element="also-me">
        other text
        <div class="but-not-me">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Above, notice we did not use `querySelectorAll` as no additional document queries are needed. However, some obvious improvements would be -

1. define your tree's shape as a separate function, `branch`
2. define a helper for repeated task, `allToTree`

```js
const branch = (element = "", children = []) =>    // 1
  ({ element, children })

const allToTree = (nodes = []) =>                  // 2
  Array.from(nodes).flatMap(toTree)
```

`toTree` is now free from complexity. Our intention is clear and each function is easy to write, test, and maintain -

```js
const toTree = ({ dataset = {}, children = [] }) =>
  dataset.element === undefined
    ? allToTree(children)
    : [ branch(dataset.element, allToTree(children) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter()` to filter out the elements without `data-element` attribute.

**But** in order to include the wrapper div, you may need to add `data-element` attribute too, as followings.

```js
const root = document.querySelector('[data-element="from-here"]');

function traverse(node) {
  if (node.dataset.element) {
    return {
      element: node.dataset.element,
      children: Array.from(node.querySelectorAll(':scope > div'))
        .filter(child => {
          return child.dataset.element || Array.from(child.children).some(grandChild => grandChild.dataset.element)
         // If element has dataset     or  The child has some children with dataset attribute
        })
        .map(childNode => traverse(childNode)),
    };
  } else if (Array.from(node.children).some(child => child.dataset.element)) {
    return Array.from(node.querySelectorAll(':scope > div')).filter(child => child.dataset.element).map(childNode => traverse(childNode))
  }
}

console.log(traverse(root));
```

```html
<div data-element="from-here">
  <div>skip me</div>
  <div>
    <div data-element="awesome">awesome text</div>
    <div data-element="collect-me">
      awesome text
      <div data-element="also-me">
        other text
        <div class="but-not-me">...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want (can't) to add attributes to elements I don't need.

Comment: I updated the answer as you requested. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Why not use using `node.querySelectorAll(':scope [data-element]')` instead? That would cover all elements having the attribute and not only the first layer of children.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cp21ykng/2/ or am I missing something?

Comment: That would return all decending elements on each iteration. As you can see, that returns 'also-me' twice.

Comment: @frietkot sorry I missed that, thanks for clarifying